# Need in my Bitcoin client wallets to restore

Tags: bitcoin-cli, address-generation, paper-wallet

It's been a very very long time and I need a refresher on how I get into my Bitcoin client wallet I have the seed phase to restore it I do know to do it offline to cash out some. I mined on the network any information would help thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the name of the wallet software you used?

Comment: Do you know which was the year when you mined?

Comment: Yes one of the very first ones

Comment: Yes back in early 2000